# License file (license.license) of the IntelliLock is not working

Tags: c#, intellilock

I have bought an **IntelliLock** licensing application.

However, it is not working as described in the help file or its documentation or in its Purchase page:

1. I have created an test.ilproj project.
2. Add an assembly (a DLL)
3. Lock setting (set expiration date)
4. Did some protection settings (excludes many elements for simplicity)
5. Saves master key
6. Did finalization

Then, test the above dll by referencing it in a .NET project. It was working and showing a
message as "Nag Screen! This message will disappear when a valid license file is installed."

I was very happy until this point. Then, **the trial period is reached** (I have set it one day).

I have created a license file based on the saved master key and with completely same condition with locking procedure.

The license file name is "license.license". I have put this file in the same place with the locked DLL. Then, built the application and ran it.
It was showing the Nag screen again.

**I have tested both the Hardware Id and other options?** it was not working. Can someone have the same experiences?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I emailed the support http://www.eziriz.com/support.htm and they were every helpful.  In the end I found out Intellilock creates a new DLL in a subfolder and the new DLL is the one that is locked and not the original one.

It's nice to have good support when you spending money like that.

Comment: What is the name of the DLL?

Comment: @dnennis - I guess you already you forgot about this question... for any others - intellilock locks YOUR assemblies, and locates them into a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this, the answer to the last question, from @dnennis, is 'same as the original DLL'.  IntelliLock creates a new subfolder called '(your name)_Locked' and the locked DLL is stored in there.